# A corollary to the Hahn-Banach theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed space and $Y\subseteq X$ be a subspace with $\ell\colon Y\to\mathbb{R}$. Then there exists $L\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $L$ is linear, $L(y)=\ell(y)$ for every $y\in Y$, and $\|L\|_{X^*}=\|\ell\|_{Y^*}$

I know how to get the function $L\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$ with $L$ is linear and $L(y)=\ell(y)$ for every $y\in Y$, by considering the function $p\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $p(x):=\|\ell\|_{Y^*}\|x\|$ and applying the Hahn-Banach theorem. Moreover, since
$$
\{\ell(y):y\in Y\}\subseteq\{L(x):x\in X\},
$$
I see that $\|\ell\|_{Y^*}\leq\|L\|_{X^*}$. However, I don't see how to get the reverse inequality, i.e., $\|\ell\|_{Y^*}\geq\|L\|_{X^*}$.

I know that $L(x)\leq p(x)=\|\ell\|_{Y^*}\|x\|$. I would like to say that $|L(x)|\leq p(x)$, but I don't believe this to be true.

---

**EDIT**: In my text, the Hahn-Banach theorem produces a function $L\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$ with $L(x)\leq p(x)$, for every $x\in X$. However, on Wikipedia, it says the Hahn-Banach theorem produces a function $L\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$ with $|L(x)|\leq p(x)$, for every $x\in X$. If the latter, is correct, then it's immediate. Which is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $L(x)\geq 0$ then $L(x)=|L(x)|$ and there are no problems. Otherwise:

$|L(x)|=-L(x)=L(-x)\leq p(-x)=p(x)$

So we get the required inequality anyway. Here we use the real Hahn-Banach theorem. There is also a complex version of it, which immediately gives $|L(x)|\leq p(x)$.

Comment: So simple, thank you for clearing this up.

Comment: I'm guess that $p(-x)\neq p(x)$ (where $p(x)$ is the sublineaer function used in the Hahn-Banach theorem) in general, correct? I mean, for this function $p(x)$ it's obvious that $p(x)=p(-x)$. However, in general we only know that $p(ax)=ap(x)$ for $a\geq0$ for a sublinear function.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. For example, the Minkowski functional in general doesn't satisfy $p(x)=p(-x)$.

Comment: Thank you, I'm about to read about the Minkowski functional now!